# GCC error No such file or directory when including a separate file

Tags: c, gcc

When I try to compile including the file `stack.h` my GCC gives me the error "No such file or directory"

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -o Ou1 ou1.c -I C:\Users\NAME\Documents\C programmering\DOA\stack.h
```

The code looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include "stack.h"
```

I've tried to change its folder and changing the `.h` to `.c` and the `.c` to `.h`.

Comment: The `-I` (upper-case i) argument expects a path to a *directory*. The compiler add that directory to its list of directories it uses to search for header files.

Comment: I think i know what you mean, but if i try to compile with only the directory i still get the same error 
C:\Users\ricka\Documents\C programmering\DOA>gcc -std=c99 -Wall -o Ou1 Ou1.c -I C:\Users\USER\Documents\C programmering\DOA
gcc: error: programmering\DOA: No such file or directory

Edit: Solved by removing the -I and directory command and just letting the compiler search the same folder

Comment: If you read the error closely you will see that it doesn't fint ***`programmering\DOA`***, which it thinks is an input source file. Few command-line environments can handle spaces in paths and names without quoting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, `-I` expects a path to a directory. Secondly, your path contains spaces, so you should enclose it in quotes to make sure it's not wrongly treated as two different arguments:

```
gcc -std=c99 -Wall -o Ou1 ou1.c -I "C:\Users\NAME\Documents\C programmering\DOA"
```